# Please identify this flower with variety/species & color classification...?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image][image]

Please identify this flower with variety/species & color classification...?

Comment: Probably some kind of Chrysanthemum variety, but need to see the leaves properly too

Comment: I have uploaded with leaves Bamboo...

Comment: Not sure what it is - I still think Chrysanthemum variety, what's known as a 'Pot Mum', but the leaves aren't well developed, there being more flower than foliage. Pot mums come in hundreds of varieties.

Comment: Can't find this particular one on line, most are not named other than 'pot mum' but example of red and red/white one here https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=daisy+type+pot+mum+with+red+at+base+of+white+petals&oq=dai&aqs=chrome.1.69i59l2j0j69i60j69i61j69i60.11292j0j4&client=tablet-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=ifTkvcUOdW3cKM%3A

Comment: How big are the flowers, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

It has to be Shasta Daisy; Leucanthemum X superbum.  I am serious!!  You can't make this up!!  Excellent perennial to have in mass 'sweeps' throughout your woody perennials. [Shasta Daisy](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/wildseed/36/36.7a.jpeg&imgrefurl=http://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/wildseed/36/36.7.html&h=375&w=424&tbnid=25V9zfVfBHJWdM:&tbnh=177&tbnw=200&docid=7HYeKrZrMtp37M&itg=1&usg=__wBm-IRjJ3qo1v2lEULasrm5Hd2A=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-6InzxovQAhWJrFQKHRrZA2kQ_B0ImgEwCg)  Plant these guys in the garden now.  Hopefully there is enough time to acclimate for winter.  Next year, cut the flowers off as soon as possible.  The plants will grow more vigorously and will perform beyond your imagination...grins.

Comment: Leaves aren't right for shasta daisy; the rows of petals are layered, not single, and the petals appear to have a touch of red or pink at the bases - all of which makes me conclude its not Leucanthemum vulgare.

Comment: Huh...there are a number of new varieties to include doubles.  I dunno, I transplanted 50 million of 'em one year and went nuts.  IDing stuff over the internet is just weird.  Hands on I am fine, pictures just don't do the same job pulling stuff up in my memory...grins!

Comment: These leaves look like Leucanthemum in the shade.  Also a bit of whitefly as well, no problemo this time of year (I think).  The leaves are mostly elongated, oblong and more sharply serrated like the immature leaves in the photo...

Comment: I see the superficial similarity to shasta daisy, but no shasta daisy I've ever seen has these little red bits at the base of the petals...seen it in some Zinnia, entirely possible in pot mum,  but  never in Leucanthemum

Comment: I am not trying to promote my ID at all...there is one other identification and that would be these daisy looking plants, there are only a few that have one flower one stalk.  The red is also part of the OLD AGE of white petals in the shade, I think...anyhoo.

Comment: Now I see what you are talking about Bamboo.  With the red at the base of the petals.  Still not a deal breaker, grins.  This is so very much fun!!  IDing plants with PLENTY of feedback is wonderful.  To simply ID something without ever knowing if one is right or wrong, is sorta lame, HUH!!??  Grins.

Answer (score 0):

I conferred with my sister, and she believes that it is an Oxeye Daisy ([Leucanthemum vulgare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucanthemum_vulgare)), and one of the best to eat (she used to forage for them a lot). She says if it smells like cat urine, it's a Shasta Daisy. If it just has a mild aroma to it, it's probably an Oxeye Daisy. She says the Oxeye Daisy has very delicious, juicy, crisp greens from early spring until well after the winter snowfall (although I should add that if you're allergic to things in the daisy family, like ragweed, you might be careful); they're crispier and much tastier if they have lots of shade and water. They have thicker and darker green leaves than Shasta Daisies. Shasta Daisies will have dark green leaves if they're in the shade, however (but the Shasta Daisy leaves will be longer and not so oval as the Oxeye).

About Chrysanthemums, she says Chrysanthemums have a thicker, lighter stalk (almost like small celery—and Chrysanthemums are also edible, but the flowers in your picture are not a Chrysanthemum according to her). However, it should be noted that Oxeye Daisies are also known as Chrysanthemum leucanthemum (so, I don't know whether they're daisies or chrysanthemums, but they look more like daisies).

EDIT: Noting Bamboo's comments to Stormy's answer, there appears to be purple on some of the flowers, on the petals near the yellow portion of the flower that I'm not sure appears in the Oxeye Daisy.

Here's a zoomed in close-up of the pixels that make up the purple color on the flower that I was talking about (which I first thought was blue, and if we were talking about the same thing, others thought it was red): [image: Purple color on the flower]

FYI: If you want to know how I zoomed in so close, while using the Xubuntu Linux operating system, I hold alt, and scroll with the mouse wheel, to zoom in (which zoom functionality is not the same as the web browser's). Then, because that only zooms in so far, I took a screenshot (with the print screen key), and then zoomed in on the screenshot to make the pixels bigger.

Comment: I purchased this plant from a nursery. They told me that it is a kind of Mum...

Comment: Well...it kinda sort of is like a mum...grins.  Daisy, or mum...are common names to infer a type of look...like a sunflower looks like a mum, yes?  The sunflower is the TOP of the evolutionary chart of dicots.  (Orchids the top of monocots)...so the template is used quite a bit...works well. Whenever you buy anything you are not familiar with make those sales people TEACH you all about the product...it is included with the price, don't cha know?  Like your doctors...make them teach you what they know...!!

Comment: Shule, I'd like to hear more from your sister...I've heard similar verbiage in the past from the more earthly, hands on type gardeners, especially those that get into the edibles and herbal use plants.  I've had wilderness food plant training but just not enough.  And one just can't learn that stuff from classes, books or the internet.  Welp, maybe classes out of doors but who gets to do that anymore?

Comment: We can talk about it in chat, if you like, but while I'm taking up a comment anyway, I'll note that she's pretty into edible wild plants and herbs. I don't know if she noticed the purple on the flower petals, but she didn't say anything when I said I thought they just looked white and yellow (speaking of the color classification part of the question). I guess we were mostly looking at the first picture, since it's closer up. I recommend that Vajresh N. Achar (or someone) edit the question to point out the subtle color and what the nursery said about them being a kind of Mum.

Comment: @Shule- yea, purplish red, although in the pics, it looks more like dark red - not that it matters, it still means it ain't Leucanthemum!

Comment: Why do we have this weird picture here? Anything to do with the original question?

Comment: It's from the picture of the flower (the purple on the flower in the second picture in the original question, zoomed in so you can see the color more clearly for what it is). It's there to help with identification and helping to determine color classification (since the color in the weird picture is the color in the flower). It's there to show how what I originally said was likely incorrect, and that it really is purple (not a pure blue or red).